# F# Interop with C# function that has generic return type

Tags: generics, f#, interop, c#-to-f#

When I have a generic function in C#, where the generic argument defines the return type of the function only, F# seems incapable of infering the generic argument. I also do not know how to type-annotate this.

For example, the following C# function is very common in lightweight ORMs, such as dapper.net and ServiceStack-ORM-Lite:

```c#
public T Get<T>(string sql)
{
    //.... 
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    //....
    return obj;
}
```

let say i try and use this in F#... firstly by type inference:

```f#
let GetCustomer sql : Customer = 
    MyCSharpObj.Get(sql)
```

Or, I try to annotate the type (not even sure if this syntax is correct):

```f#
let GetCustomer sql : Customer = 
    MyCSharpObj.Get<Customer>(sql)
```

In both instances, i get the compile error (on the `MyCSharpObj.Get` line):

> Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.

How do a use a method of this kind in F# ?

Comment: Does this help?  let GetCustomer (sql : string) : Customer =  ...

Comment: Yes! That works. Which is odd as it was correctly inferring sql as a string. Post your answer and ill accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my comment:

```
let GetCustomer (sql : string) : Customer = ..
```

It is the "sql" it is having trouble identifying the type of, not the return value.